# Why doesn't Border.BorderBrush binding to TextBox.BorderBrush always work?

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm creating a custom `UserControl`, and part of it involves placing a Border on top of a `TextBox`. I'd like the `Border.BorderBrush` to always match that of the `TextBox.BorderBrush`.

You'd think this would work:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />

<Border
    BorderThickness="2"
    BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=MyTextBox}"
    />
```

Yet when the `TextBox.BorderBrush` changes based on whether it's focused, the `Border.BorderBrush` is not updated accordingly. By the way, I'm using custom styling on the controls.

Comment: As you mentioned that you're using custom styling, can you verify that the `BorderBrush` is applying if you're not applying those `Styles`? There can be something in your `CustomStyle` that might be overriding your `BorderBrush`.

Comment: The TextBox's BorderBrush property doesn't change when it is focused. What you see is the BorderBrush of an element in the TextBox's ControlTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens Ah, yes, you're right. Thanks.